# In AEM how to add a new node called “listeners” in the component dialog ,without using dialog.xml file

Tags: aem

Actaully i am using  "before submit" listener to do some validation for my selection box 
I have reffered the following link:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/classic_dialog_validation.html.

But "before submit" method calling only when i place  ,
dialog listener in the dialog root level only.

how to place  dialog listener in dialog root level(I checked in my project there is no dialog.xml file ,they using only java code  to construct  component dialog).

Can anyone please help me in  this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmlGj.png)

Dialog property construction code :

@DialogField(name ="./validateProgram",

fieldLabel = "Validate Program",

```
fieldDescription = "(synchronized)",

        additionalProperties = {
                 @Property(renderIn = Property.RenderValue.TOUCH,
                                name = "validation",
                                value = "validation-program")
                 },

         listeners = {
             @Listener(name ="beforesubmit",
                          value = "function(dialog){" + 
                        "return programValidation.beforeSubmit(dialog);"+ 
                       "}")
                    })

       @Selection(
                type ="select",
                optionsProvider = " ",
                dataSource = "/resourcetype/data")

       public final String validateProgram;
```

Java Script code:

window.onload = function() {

```
 programValidation.init();
```

};

var  programValidation= programValidation|| (function($) {

```
function initialize() {
};

function validate() {
    alert("inside validate method");
    var res = true;
    return res;
};

return {
    beforeSubmit: validate,        
    init: initialize
}
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: please add relevant code parts to your post.

Comment: Added relevant code parts. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the cq [component maven plugin](https://github.com/OlsonDigital/cq-component-maven-plugin) this a very vital piece of information to get your question answered.

I have not used this plugin before, but in your case, I assume you are looking for the [Listener](http://code.digitalatolson.com/cq-component-maven-plugin/apidocs/com/citytechinc/cq/component/annotations/Listener.html) annotation where you can set the name as `beforesubmit` and the value as `function(){alert(1)}`

you'll probably have to set the annotation on a *local variable* similar to how you would annotate a dialog field '@DialogField', find more docs in the plugin's usage page here: http://code.digitalatolson.com/cq-component-maven-plugin/usage.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support. Found the following way to solve the issue .

I added ValidateFields method from within the  2 listeners (FIELD_LISTENER_LOAD_CONTENT and FIELD_LISTENER_SELECTION_CHANGED)

```
function ValidateFields(dialog) {
dialog.on("beforesubmit", function(e) {
   if(<condtion failed>)
    CQ.Ext.Msg.alert(CQ.I18n.getMessage("Error"), CQ.I18n.getMessage("<error message>"));
    return false;
   } else {
    return true;
   }
}, this);
}
```